# How to find max value in pair RDD?

Tags: scala, apache-spark, pyspark

I have a spark pair RDD (key, count) as below

```
Array[(String, Int)] = Array((a,1), (b,2), (c,1), (d,3))
```

How to find the key with highest count using spark scala API?

EDIT: datatype of pair RDD is org.apache.spark.rdd.RDD[(String, Int)]

Comment: how did you find datatype of pair rdd?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Use `Array.maxBy` method:

```
val a = Array(("a",1), ("b",2), ("c",1), ("d",3))
val maxKey = a.maxBy(_._2)
// maxKey: (String, Int) = (d,3)
```

or `RDD.max`:

```
val maxKey2 = rdd.max()(new Ordering[Tuple2[String, Int]]() {
  override def compare(x: (String, Int), y: (String, Int)): Int = 
      Ordering[Int].compare(x._2, y._2)
})
```

Answer (score 14):

Use `takeOrdered(1)(Ordering[Int].reverse.on(_._2))`:

```
val a = Array(("a",1), ("b",2), ("c",1), ("d",3))
val rdd = sc.parallelize(a)
val maxKey = rdd.takeOrdered(1)(Ordering[Int].reverse.on(_._2))
// maxKey: Array[(String, Int)] = Array((d,3))
```

Quoting the note from [RDD.takeOrdered](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/org/apache/spark/rdd/RDD.html#takeOrdered(num:Int)(implicitord:Ordering[T]):Array[T]):

> This method should only be used if the resulting array is expected to be small, as all the data is loaded into the driver's memory.

Comment: Is this any better than using Rubber Duck's [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/46390660/29771)?

Comment: @Glenn I'm not so sure given the note I've just added. You'd have to check it out yourself (and report back).

Answer (score 11):

For Pyspark:

Let `a` be the pair RDD with keys as String and values as integers then

```
a.max(lambda x:x[1])
```

returns the key value pair with the maximum value. Basically the max function orders by the return value of the lambda function.

Here `a` is a pair RDD with elements such as `('key',int)` and `x[1]` just refers to the integer part of the element.

Note that the `max` function by itself will order by key and return the max value.

Documentation is available at https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.5.0/api/python/pyspark.html#pyspark.RDD.max

Comment: The question is related to Scala not python

Comment: any idea how can we print the entire tuple? Above answer gives max value of x[1]. I also want value of x[0] where x[1] is maximum

Comment: @user2543622 no, it returns both values.

Answer (score 5):

Spark RDD's are more efficient timewise when they are left as RDD's and not turned into Arrays

```
strinIntTuppleRDD.reduce((x, y) => if(x._2 > y._2) x else y)
```