# How can i filter records from JavaPairRDD

Tags: java, apache-spark

i am doing one simple example of WordCount in Apache spark now at last i am getting words count **I want to filter only Unique words from it.**

```
public class SparkClass {
    public static void main(String[] args) {

    String file = "/home/bhaumik/Documents/my";
    JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext("local", "SimpleApp");
    JavaRDD<String> lines = sc.textFile("/home/bhaumik/Documents/myText", 5)
            .flatMap(new FlatMapFunction<String, String>() {

                @Override
                public Iterable<String> call(String t) throws Exception {
                    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                    return Arrays.asList(t.split(" "));
                }
            });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> pairs = lines.mapToPair(new PairFunction<String, String, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Tuple2<String, Integer> call(String t) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return new Tuple2<String, Integer>(t, 1);
        }
    });

    JavaPairRDD<String, Integer> counts = pairs.reduceByKey(new Function2<Integer, Integer, Integer>() {

        @Override
        public Integer call(Integer v1, Integer v2) throws Exception {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            return v1 + v2;
        }
    });
}
```

}

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886275/how-to-find-max-value-in-pair-rdd

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
JavaPairRDD<String,Integer> uniqueIP = counts.filter(newFunction<Tuple2<String,Integer>,Boolean()>{
   @Override
   public Boolean call(Tuple<String, Integer> v1) throws Exception {
   return v1._2.equals(1);
   }
});
```

**This is how I solved the problem...**

Answer (score 2):

In *counts* you have a RDD with the key and its number of appearances. What you cant now is to get the **minimum value**, so you should just to **reduce**

```
Tuple2<String, Integer> minApp = counts.reduce((a, b) -> (a._2 > b._2)? b : a);
```

Comment: it is not possible to get it in to JavaPairRDD or is there any method to convert Tuple2 to JavaPairRDD ??

Comment: In this case it don't make much sense. Other option could  be to sort  the whole RDD and get the first element

Comment: actually i am doing same on my log file in which i am fetching IP from it and then now i want unique IP that why i am asking you? :(

Comment: Thanks for your help and efforts.