# spark finding max value and the associated key

Tags: python, apache-spark, tuples, max, pyspark

My question is based upon [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886275/how-to-find-max-value-in-pair-rdd/35245519#comment58951912_35245519). I have a spark pair RDD (key, count): `[(a,1), (b,2), (c,1), (d,3)]`.

How can I find the both the key with highest count and the actual count?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
(sc
    .parallelize([("a",1), ("b",5), ("c",1), ("d",3)])
    .max(key=lambda x:x[1]))
```

does return `('b', 5)`, not only `5`. The first parameter of `max` is the key used for comparison (explicited here), but max still returns the whole value, here the complete tuple.

Comment: You are the best :)

Comment: Thank you @Mariam!

Answer (score 1):

```
val myRDD = sc.parallelize(Array(
     |      | ("a",1),
     |      | ("b",5),
     |      | ("c",1),
     |      | ("d",3))).sortBy(_._2,false).take(1)
```

Sorting on the values in descending order and taking topmost element.

Comment: Sorting just to get the max is likely to be slower