# Get max record from RDD

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I want to get a maximum value from an RDD using ***RDD.max***  in Scala. My RDD contains bunch of VOs with field ***duration*** (***Long***  type). I tried with following code but It works well only with **Int** and not with **Long** (as per Document)

```
    val vo1 = new MyVO()    
    vo1.setDuration(1234L)

    val vo2 = new MyVO()
    vo2.setDuration(123L)

    val a = Array(vo1, vo2)    
    val sc = prepareConfig()
    val rdd = sc.parallelize(a)

    val maxKey2 = rdd.max()(new Ordering[MyVO]() {
      override def compare(x: MyVO, 
                           y: MyVO): Long = 
        Ordering[Long].compare(x.duration, y.duration)
    })

    println(maxKey2.duration)
```

I'm referring to this post 
 [How to find max value in pair RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26886275/how-to-find-max-value-in-pair-rdd) . 
But I don't know how to deal with Long in my case. Any help highly appreciated

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The **result** of `compare` in that context is always an `Int` (no matter which types you compare, have a look at the definition of `compare` in trait [`Ordering`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/index.html#scala.math.Ordering)).

As you are comparing `Long` values, the `compare` function can be simplified to:

```
override def compare(x: TransactionSummeryVO, y: TransactionSummeryVO): Int = 
    x.duration.compareTo(y.duration)
```

Comment: Thanks for the response and it worked.  I have a basic query here. using VOs in RDDs are recommended? i will be having millions of records in  RDD and each VO represents one row after some point of transformation  in my job.  is it proper way ?

Comment: Yes, it's OK to use case classes.