# Use Scala to Find The Most Common 'uncommon' word in keys

Tags: scala, apache-spark

I need to find the most common 'uncommon' word in a text file. I have a list of common words and my map of the most common words in the file.

Let's say I have

```
val commonWords = List("the","a","I","is")
```

and map

```
val mostUsedWordsFromTextFile
```

How might I loop over the map mostUsedWordsFromTextFile until I hit a word *not* in list commonWords?

Comment: Why is `mostUsedWordsFromTextFile` a `Map`?

Comment: it's a flatMap of the key-values of each word in the text file, with the values being number of occurrences.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming your input is:

```
val input = RDD(("hello", 4), ("the", 2), ("world", 6))
```

then you could:

- filter out words which are part of common words
- take the most popular word from the remaining ones

this way:

```
val commonWords = Set("the", "a", "I", "is")

val result = input
  .filter { case (word, count) => !commonWords.contains(word) } // RDD(("hello", 4), ("world", 6))
  .takeOrdered(1)(Ordering[Int].on { case (word, count) => -count }) // Array(("world", 6))
  .head // ("world", 6)
  ._1 // world
```

See [How to find max value in pair RDD?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26886275/9297144)
 for different ways of implementing `maxBy` on an `RDD`.

Comment: If OP is open to it, you should use a `Set` rather than a `List` for `commonWords`, for better performance. Also, use `maxBy` rather than `sortBy` to avoid sorting the whole RDD, and keeping only the greatest value

Comment: @CyrilleCorpet you're right. I always go for the full sort when I shouldn't.